# jQuery Form Submit and Display Results not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, form-submit

I am trying post a form data using AJAX and display the result in a div. Despite of all my best efforts, I failed.

Here is the code I am using with jQuery 1.8.3

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="forecastform">
    <input type="text" name="weatherloc" class="weatherloc">
    <input type="submit" name="weathersubmit" class="weathersubmit" value="Get Forecast">
</form>

<div class="wfposts"></div>
```

JavaScript at head section:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('#forecastform').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var term = jQuery('.weatherloc').val();
            var url = <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/local-forecast-process.php';?>;

                 var posting = jQuery.post( url, { weatherloc: term } );

                    posting.done(function( data ) {
                    var content = jQuery( data );
                    jQuery( ".wfposts" ).empty().append( content );
                    });
            });
        </script>
```

First of all, the page reloads ignoring the `event.preventDefault();`
I am not sure if the data is being sent or not as the div isn't being populated after the page loads.

Someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error, unquoted strings!

Replace:

```
var url = <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/local-forecast-process.php';?>;
```

with

```
var url  = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/local-forecast-process.php";
```

and add a DOM ready handler if the javascript isn't included after the elements.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.. Sorry to bother again, Is there any way I can add a ajax loading image with this code?

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap this up in $.ready since the element `forecastform` is not there when jQuery is trying to select it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#forecastform').submit(function(event) {
   ....
   ...
   })
}
```